# ParserError 859 while parsing a json in a raketask

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, parsing, rake

So I have a model called MeteoStation and I want to create a rake task thats create MeteoStations that are in the json with this format:

```
[{
  "code": "Q0934X",
  "name": "PIBA",
  "longlat": 5.260838 7.2645,
  "altitude": 43
}]
```

This is my rake task code:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
namespace :import_stations do #rake import_stations:aemet
   desc "Import MeteoStations from meteo_stations.json"
   task aemet: :environment do
      meteo_station_list = JSON.parse(File.read('meteo_stations.json'))
      meteo_station_list.each do |station|
      MeteoStation.create(station.to_h)
     end
   end
end
```

And this is schema.rb

```
  create_table "meteo_stations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "code"
    t.string "type"
    t.geometry "longlat", limit: {:srid=>0, :type=>"st_point"}
    t.decimal "altitude"
    t.json "settings"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

I'm getting this error and I dont know where comes from

```
JSON::ParserError: 859: unexpected token at '{
```

I've been trying a lot of things and I'm still stuck, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `"longlat": 5.260838 7.2645` is not valid which is giving you the syntax error

Comment: could be! what is the correct format then?

Comment: Depends! it could be in an array `[5.260838, 7.2645]` or a string with space/comma or a separator of your choice `"5.260838 7.2645"` or the latitude and longitude can be two different parameters.

Comment: The correct format would be latitide longitude and not longlat (which sounds strange) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709. I would use two different columns.